# Can I marry and divorce two sisters every 2 years so that I can be with them both?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, muslim-practices

My wife wants me to marry her sister. I've explained to her that Islam does not allow two sisters in marriage with the same guy at the same time.

She says that she can take Khula from me, so that I can marry with her sister.

She also says that she and her sister want me to be their husband turn by turn every two years. **Is it possible in Islam ?**

Comment: That is very close to being a Mutaa marriage. Can you elaborate if you are looking for a Sunni or Shia perspective?

Comment: Also what happens if you were to have kids? Would you still divorce the mother of your children?

Comment: It is not possible to repeatedly divorce and remarry the same person.You will not be able to remarry her after the third time. الطلاق مرتان فإمساك بمعروف أو تسريح بإحسان

Comment: @UmH After the third marriage, isn't the concept of 'Halala' applicable? (No disrespect to Arif or his wife but a generic question)

Comment: @Ahmed halala is a concept that is not in accordance to the rules of shari'a. Which also applies to the suggestion of Arifs wife assuming it is her idea.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Surah Baqarah, Ayah 230

Comment: @Ahmed it says she must marry someone else (and marriage must be consumed) **not** she must marry someone who marries her in order to divorce her (this is halala when ex husband and wife find a man who wants to do this). So if this guy marries her with the intention of divorce this marriage might be legal but the intention is haram. And BTW even with halala the next divorce would be final so how often would they practice halala later? Only the thought of this practice is awful.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Oh I didn't know people got married with the intention of getting divorced after it's consummation. That definitely isn't part of the shariah. What I was referring to was a woman getting married without with the normal intention of starting a new married life but to unforeseeable situation (new husband dies/divorces) she comes back to the first husband as allowed in 2:230. I also concur that the question asked by OP too would be rejected by most if not all ulema.

Comment: i dont think thats appropriate even in cultural perspective..

Answer (score 1):

In islam marriage is not meant to be temporary but lasting and you cannot intend to marry someone for a specific time as it would not be a valid nikah. Allah knows best and if my answer is wrong it is my fault so please forgive me for that.